# trouble sending to php database

Tags: html, forms, doctype

hi there i have a form and needs to send data to the database but every time i click submit than the page diverts me to the php page i created any help please

i have tried the following

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BoZc5oUioA&t=585s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78RUaIe4X0A&t=621s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtOj65lRfFA&t=56s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhLAB1wwzNk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n35Jn2nP9iU&t=181s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HVKizgcfjo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEpg1GE0edI&t=38s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtOj65lRfFA&t=71s

Comment: Is diverting to the PHP page not the indented functionality? Normally when you click a form, the user is redirected to the `action` PHP file where the form is processed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you show us some code you have written?